# can't access when doing ls

Tags: 20.04, directory

I am facing a weird problem on Ubuntu 20.04.1
I am trying to count the files in a folder using `ls -al` I keep getting `ls: cannot access`

this is the server (on EC2)

```
>lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

I did `ls -al Images_dl/|wc -l`

```
ls: cannot access 'Images_dl/a4c970c4-b974-4e66-ac30-de4548f93a12.ico': No such file or directory
1636242
```

Using python shell

```
import os
len(os.listdir('Images_dl'))
1710423
```